# Hyperref jumping one line below the chapter title with Adobe Reader

Tags: hyperref

With the Built-in Viewer in `Texmaker`, when I click on a chapter title in the table of content, this jumps correctly on the corresponding chapter title, but when I do it with Adobe Reader, this jumps one line below, for both unnumbered and numbered chapters. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{hyperref,titlesec, lipsum}

\titleformat{\chapter}[block]
{\filcenter\normalfont\Large\bfseries}{\chaptertitlename\ \thechapter.}{0.3em}{}
\titlespacing*{\chapter}{0pt}{-50pt}{40pt} %Cancels the automatic space added (50pt above the title and 40pt after it)

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\phantomsection
\chapter*{Title of unnumbered Chapter}
\markboth{Title of unnumbered Chapter}{}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{Title of unnumbered Chapter}

\lipsum[3-8]

\chapter{This is a very very very long title of Chapter bla bla bla bla bla bla bla and bla bla bla}

\lipsum[3-6]

\end{document}
```

With this reduced code I can see that the problem comes from my changements of the title formatting. How could I improve it please to solve my `Hyperref` problem while keeping the same presentation?

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem. See how to construct a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Thank you for your comment, I edited my question with a MWE and it allowed me to define where the problem is.

Comment: Thanks for the MWE! Add in `\usepackage{showframe}` to really see the problem. Your chapter title is already in the header area, while the hyperref links you to the top of the text body.

Comment: Ah ok thank you, so I could I make Hyperref to jump to the header area instead of the top of the text body please?

Comment: titlesec is not fully supported by hyperref, see the readme.pdf of hyperref.

Comment: Which alternative to titlesec do I have to obtain the same presentation for my titles, that would be compatible with hyperref?